# xargs loop with input variable for use in multi-command

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a text file with various IP addresses.

I would like to cycle through each, and issue a command:

```
cat ips.txt | xargs -L 1 `ssh me@__IP__ echo "text" > file; reboot;`
```

But I'm unsure how to pass the xargs value to **_*IP*_**.

Could someone explain how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need either `cat` or `xargs` for this: a simple `read` in a loop would suffice:

```
while read -r IP;do
    ssh me@$IP echo "text" > file
    reboot
done < ips.txt
```

For future reference, what you want for `xargs` can be achieved with the `-I` option: you supply a name after `-I` and any instances of that name in the command itself will be replaced by the arguments `xargs` receives on the pipe:

```
... | xargs -L 1 -I myip ssh me@myip 'echo "text">file;reboot'
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using `-I` earlier, which was actually rebooting *my* server by mistake for some reason :) thanks this is very helpful!

Comment: @d-_-b This is because the shell (rightfully) interprets the semicolon as terminating the `xargs` command. To avoid this, quote your arguments: `... shh me@myip 'echo text > file;reboot'`

Comment: From [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs): `-I  Implies -x and -L 1`

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you can do it in parallel:

```
parallel --slf ips.txt --nonall 'echo "text" > file; reboot;'
```